# how to regex the string between two tokens and return string without the tokens?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, token

Fighting with regex....

I'm using this to find pieces of HTML-string between certain elements:

```
 for (i = 0; i < 2; i += 1) {
   target = block[i];   // like BODY or HEAD
   regex = RegExp('<' + target + '>(.)+</' + target + '>');
   // in case string passed includes breaks/spaces
   data = data.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"").replace(/\s+/g," ")
             .match(regex);
   entry = data[0].replace(/<!-- [\s\S]*? -->/g, '');
   console.log(entry);
 }
```

While this works fine, it returns something like this:

```
<head>....everthing I want ....</head>
```

**Question:**
How do I need to modifiy the regex, so that I can still specifiy the element whose content I need, but which returns only the content and not content & tokens (like `<head></head>`).

Thanks!

Comment: Use Ambers solution and also move the parens to include the `+` like this `'<' + target + '>(.+)</' + target + '>'`

Comment: Is there anything wrong with `$(target).each(function(){ console.log($(this).html()); })` apart from the comment nodes?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: actually no. I had some templates, where comments <!-- denote templates -->, but this one does not, so also trying this.

Comment: Of course, spaces still have to be collapsed with regex, and comment nodes can be removed with either `contents().filter()` or regex but yes, I'm still unsure of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Fabricio: I'm working on a plugin that pulls in snippets of code, which I prefer to be snippets, but which come as (uncompressed) HTML pages (think of a page with a button). I'm having to extract the bits and pieces of the snippet page to use, because I cannot append the full snippet as is. So I created the regex to filter for script/css, which I'm appending to page head, plus whats in the body (e.g. the solo button), which goes into the page. I solved it with Ambers answer, so I'm a happy camper. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. `=]` Though you know, regex is not really [suitable for parsing HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1331430). That means, your regex will fail to match if the tag has any html attribute e.g. `<body onload=...>`, or if `<body>` is inside a comment node and so forth. Hopefully you aren't using thar regex on the wild. `:P`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: well... technically it's being loaded as a string (requirejs text plugin). So not really sure, but this is a temp patch anyway until I find a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the first matching group instead of the whole match.

```
regex = RegExp('<' + target + '>(.+)</' + target + '>');
```

and then...

```
entry = data[1].replace(/<!-- [\s\S]*? -->/g, '');
```

Comment: Note the slight edit - you need `(.+)` (one matching group of repeated characters) rather than `(.)+` (repeated matching groups of one character each).

Comment: nice! I was looking at my `[1]` returning `>` wondering what to make of it :-) Thanks a lot!